# Xcode: LaunchScreen.storyboard is not showing up

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I'm trying to set up the launch screen and initial view of my app. However, I can't get either to show up.

I have this set up:

[image]

[image]

Am I missing a step? Shouldn't I be seeing a page with "blah" on it as the launch screen? Instead, when I run the simulator it's just black.

Also, I don't understand why my initial view isn't showing up either.

In my AppDelegate.swift file:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?

  func application(application: UIApplication,
      didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        self.window?.rootViewController = self.rootViewController()
    return true
  }

  private func rootViewController() -> UIViewController {
    return MapViewController.init()
  }

}
```

And my MapViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
        label.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.text = "I am a test label"
        self.view.addSubview(label)
        NSLog("heyyyy!!") // <----------------- doesn't get printed either, so I think I'm missing something again...
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Sorry for the noob questions.

== UPDATE ==

I do get these 2 warnings when I build it:

> file:///Users/emai/Documents/ios/Sherpa/SherpaNewYork/LaunchScreen.storyboard: warning: Unsupported Configuration: Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier for runtime access via -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:.
>
> /Users/emai/Documents/ios/Sherpa/SherpaNewYork/LaunchScreen.storyboard:9: Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier for runtime access via -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:.

Comment: When you build, are there any warnings about your launch screen?

Comment: yeh let me paste it for you

Comment: Don't ignore warnings. Fix all warnings. An app really should (must) compile warning free.

Comment: Yeh make sense... I updated the question with the warnings

Comment: Not true re "must". In a complex project (especially under real-world time constraints), managing ALL warnings is entirely impractical, especially regarding constraint issues.

Comment: Nate's answer below was the ONLY thing that fixed my issue: he suggested us to use "xcrun simctl erase all" in Terminal to clear the simulator cache.

Answer (score 12):

I also struggled with a launchscreen storyboard not showing up. I tried everything fix I could find to no avail. Then I cleared the cache on my Simulator and it worked! Turned out it was a simulator problem. I cleared the cache with this command in terminal: xcrun simctl erase all

Comment: THIS is the answer. THANK YOU. This is such a silly bug, and so tiresome. This is the only thing that finally corrected my issue of the launch screen storyboard not showing up.

Comment: Just a FYI, don't use this terminal command if you are using more than one version of Xcode on your machine. You will lose connection to your simulator and cause more headaches.

Comment: yes, this was the answer for me also... was getting so pissed off !

Comment: Thank-you for mentioning the simulator. I run more than one Xcode version so deleting the app from the simulator before rerunning cured the problem for me.

Comment: This worked for me with xcode 11.2.1 and SwiftUI template.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you haven't set up your storyboards with an entry point. Set up the first scene you want to show as the `Initial View Controller`

[image]

Comment: Awesome this solves the first scene issue right ? If I'm not using storyboards for scenes how would i set this property programmatically ?

Comment: If you aren't using storyboards then there is nothing to set up as you are loading your view controllers manually.

Comment: Then why is it just a black screen ? Because I messed up the launch screen part?

Comment: Probably because you're setting the root view controller to a plain UIViewController. Try returning an instance of a view controller that you want to return.

Comment: oops that was a test when  i was debugging the black screen. changing it back to MapViewController.init() does nothing

Answer (score 2):

sure, this answer is  a little late. ;-) Had the some problem but i fortuitous found a quiet simple solution using the Launch Screen.storyboard created with the app automatic.

Open the App-Settings and there App Icons and Launch Images

[image]

Select **Launch Screen.storyboard** in the DropDown-List, even when u think, this is already selected. The display of the screen won´t change after selecting. But when restart the project, the Launch Screen was showed!

BTW to test this tidy, u can set a breakpont in the last line of
*func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?)*

Answer (score 2):

had the same problem with the launchscreen. As mentioned from Abizern, there is no ViewController allowed. If you had one only deleting this one will not be enough some times. The LaunchScreen file could still have some connections to the ViewController which is not available any more. This is a problem, too.

My fix:

1. Delete ViewController for LaunchScreen
2. Removed connections in LaunchScreen.storyboard
3. Removed app from Device
4. Reinstall

-> Worked :)

Answer (score 1):

After trying every other answer here, I finally deleted the LaunchScreen.Storyboard file and created a new one. This was the only thing that fixed the issue for me.

Comment: This solved my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is that a launch screen is static! It does not need a controller or anything. A controller will not do anything. For the launch screen you can design the UI only using the interface builder, not via code.

Xcode should generally tell you that, if you try to set a custom controller on the launch screen view it results in an error.

Comment: So am I supposed to remove the view controller from that storyboard and just have a standalone storyboard? Xcode will manage it?

Comment: @Edmund You need one storyboard for the launch screen which is static AND one storyboard for your application where you connect the views to your controllers and outlets and all that crazy stuff

Answer (score 0):

So deleting the LaunchScreen.storyboard + LaunchScreenViewController.swift files and adding a Launch Screen.xib file worked in fixing the launch screen. This makes sense to me since the launch screen should be static and not use code.

However the view is still black after the launch screen. I'll make another SO question for that.

Comment: There is no need for a LaunchScreenViewController. It isn't used. The storyboard for the launch screen can only contain objects and layout constraints that you put on it. No code is executed. A plain Launch storyboard is all you need. I suspect that your problem is elsewhere, and you're just working around it by moving from a storyboard to a xib.

Answer (score 0):

i know it is very late but i want to share how i fixed it, if you are checking on real device then try to delete the app first, restart the handset and then reinstall the app. it will be fixed if you have followed all steps like clearing cache and settings in Target - General Tab etc.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the project navigator file filter was set to "recent". See bottom left of Xcode. I unselected recent, and the file showed up.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to uninstall and reinstall the app when testing in the simulator. No need to remove and re-create `LaunchScreen.Storyboard`.